# D8 services errors - No route found for the specified formats : */*

Tags: 8, services

I'm trying to get data from a Drupal 8 website to Go application.I created a view that it would display title and body on json format. Here is an [example](http://%20http://dev-d8go.pantheon.io/d8go/node/1)
  Th when the Go application try to get the request I got this error.

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotAcceptableHttpException: No route found for     
the specified formats : */*. in Drupal\Core\Routing\AcceptHeaderMatcher->filter() (line 
64 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AcceptHeaderMatcher.php).
```

What I'm doing wrong ? As far I know, the Go application is asking the request properly.

Just in case you are wondering about the Go app [here is the code](https://github.com/darol100/grupal/blob/master/grupal.go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the issues was on my Go App. Apparently the on my Go app.

It did not like `Header.Set("Accept:", "*/*")`.

Comment: Interesting */* should ideally fallback to one route at least

Answer (score 3):

If you update to the next beta, You will have to use: "http://dev-d8go.pantheon.io/d8go/node/1?_format=json"

Comment: I'm running the latest beta. Do you mean the upcoming beta, which is beta12?

Comment: This feature should be available for Beta 12. I try to use Beta11 and did not work. I installed a git version of the module (today) and it works.

Comment: thank you for this. I was having the same issue and now it works (with beta 12). Please note that cookie auth needs to be selected in admin/config/services/rest

Comment: You can simply add this patch, So that no need to use `?_format=json`.  [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-04-28/2854543-88.patch)